# An unexpected token "=" was found following "<identifier>". Expected tokens may include: "WITH". SQLSTATE=42601

Tags: sql, database, bash, db2

```
while [ 1 ]
do
echo "Select number from the following options"
echo "1 - Data Base Menu
2 - Customer Sale

3 - Quit"

read opt
case $opt in
    "1")
        managementMenu
            ;;
    "2") echo " Enter Sale Code"
          read eCode 
        echo " Enter client Code: "
                read cCode
        echo " Enter product "
                read product
        echo " Enter Quantity "
                read QTY
    db2 "update Sales set QTY = $QTY where SNR = '$eCode' and PNR = '$product'"
    **db2 "update Histroy set QTY = $QTY where CCN = '$cCode' and PNR = '$product'"**
            ;;

    "3")
        break
            ;;
    *) echo invalid option;;
esac
done
# cant use select * to display
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: i keep getting an error when i try to update my History table using this line db2 "update Histroy set QTY = $QTY where CCN = '$cCode' and PNR = '$product'" the error i get is the title

Comment: Could the problem be your misspelling of "History"?

Comment: i checked with display table and the tables name is definitely History

Comment: Most likely a SQL injection issue, e.g. `product` is something like `Smith's`

Comment: the input im using for product is P1

Comment: @p.s.w.g , is it possible that History is a reserved word, because i copied the table exactly to a dummy table and it worked with the dummy table

Comment: @AmrHamada I can't find any reference that lists `HISTORY` as a reserved word in DB2. See [this](http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/ibmdb2/w/wiki/7769.sql-reserved-words.aspx) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339396/all-reserved-words-of-every-dbms).

Comment: @p.s.w.g can i use this line ?  db2 " update StoreStock set QTY = QTY + $QTY where whStock.QTY >= $QTY and StoreStock.PNR = '$prod'"

Comment: There are some serious errors in the SQL syntax there. If `whStock` is another table, you need to tell the engine how the `whStock` records relate to the current `StoreStock` record. Also, it doesn't solve the SQL injection issue.

Comment: @p.s.w.g i just named the table differently which fixed the injection problem, that was different question, im new to db2 sorry, how would i fix this, the purpose is to find out if the warehouse has enough stock before updating the store stock

Answer (score 2):

Instead of executing

```
db2 "update Sales set ...
```

Try using

```
db2 -v "update Sales set ...
```

This will cause the DB2 CLP to echo the actual SQL statement it's getting, which will likely show you what's causing the error.  (i.e. as @p.s.w.g suggests)